# Browser back button firing up javascript function unintentionally

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, back

I am writing a number of HTML widgets for our Jive platform.

One of these widgets is a basic search box. I have an anonymous function that captures the value entered into the search box, appends that value to a url (search.jspa?q=myvalue) which returns a list of results on the page search.jspa. It is fired on the onclick action.

The issue I have is that when the user clicks the back button on the page of returned results, the page that contains the search widget flashes up momentarily then the list of results on the page search.jspa appears once more.

So, is there any way I can prevent this function from firing upon the back button being pressed? Some kind of built in function that prevents any javascript from running on the page?

Kinda frustrating. Thanks for your help.

Edit :

Code:

```
<script> 
document.getElementById("search-icon").onclick = function() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search-custom').value;
    var searchURL = "/search.jspa?q=" + searchTerm;
    window.location.href = searchURL;
};
$('#placeholder-text').onclick = function() {
    $('#placeholder-text').val(null)
};};
</script>
```

Comment: that could mean you are firing the function to load data on click of back button, and appending to the current datalist. or redirecting to this page and this page reloads the data and append

Comment: Yes. In my function I use window.location.href = searchURL; to redirect to the results page and this page reloads the data and append. Code below.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I have a feeling you are defining your function like this:
`function myFunction() {}`. If I remember correctly, this will fire the function when the page is loaded. What you probably want is something like this:
`myFunction = function() {}`.

Comment: <script>

document.getElementById("search-icon").onclick = function () {  
 var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search-custom').value;
 var searchURL = "/search.jspa?q="+searchTerm;
 window.location.href = searchURL;
 };

 $('#placeholder-text').onclick = function () {  
 $('#placeholder-text').val(null)
 };
 
 }; 
</script>

Comment: Prash, this is on the Homepage. It's a widget on the Jive platform and those widgets the only areas that I have the right to code. They have it locked right down. I can't see any redirect on the page however.